# Xamarin Forms - How to check setting of RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations permission on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

##### (See UPDATE below)

I have a Xamarin Forms app on Android which uses the Xamarin.Essentials library.

The app requires to run in the background to be fed location data (not particularly relevant to the question in hand, but included for context), and so must not be put to sleep by any battery optimisations that the OS might attempt.

I know that the user can manually opt out specific apps from Battery Optimizations, but as it is so crucial to the successful operation of the app, I would like the app to be able to :

1. check the Battery Optimization Opt-out permission status to ensure it is appropriately set,

and/or

2. force Android to opt the app of any battery optimizations.

I have added an entry into AndroidManifest.xml, but it doesn't seem to help, with the newly-installed app defaulting to being Battery Optimized.

##### AndroidManifest.xml

The manifest contains the following entry:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

##### Xamarin.Essentials

This library gives access to a number of permission-related info on the device, but Battery Optimizations doesn't seem to be one of them.

##### Device being used

I don't know if it's relevant, but I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra.

Can anyone offer any advice?

## UPDATE Aug 28 2021

Following the advice from contributors and with reference to the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#extending-permissions ...

##### In My Shared Code

```
public interface IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission
{
    Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync();
    Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync();
}
```

##### In My Android Project

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission))]

namespace MyAndroidProject
{
    public class RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission : Permissions.BasePlatformPermission, IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission
    {
        public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions => new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
        {
            (Android.Manifest.Permission.RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations, true)
        }.ToArray();
    }
}
```

##### On Shared App Initialization

```
// Ensure Required Permissions have been granted
var requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission = DependencyService.Get<IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission>();
            
var status = requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission.CheckStatusAsync().Result;

if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    status = requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission.RequestAsync().Result;
}
```

##### Result...

On calling `CheckStatusAsync`, the result comes back as `Granted`.

But the app settings still say otherwise...

[image]

[image]

I've tried it on both a physical device (Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra) and on an Android Emulator (Pixel 2 API 28), with same result on both.

Comment: You're not supposed to get result like that `status = requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizationPermission.RequestAsync().Result;` await for result otherwise do it as I suggested in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases), there are two ways to set Battery Optimization

An app can fire the `ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` intent to take the user directly to the `Battery Optimization`, where they can add the app.

An app holding the `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission can trigger a system dialog to let the user add the app to the exemption list directly, without going to settings. The app fires a `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` Intent to trigger the dialog.

I use [PowserManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(java.lang.String)) to check Battery Optimization.

Firstly, add `RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Then creating Interface in Shared code.

```
public interface IBattery
{
     void getbattery();     
}
```

Implementing this interface in Android platform.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ImplementBattery))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
public class ImplementBattery : IBattery
{
    public void getbattery()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = MainActivity.mac.PackageName;
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)MainActivity.mac.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        if (pm.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
            intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionIgnoreBatteryOptimizationSettings);
        else
        {
            intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations);
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + packageName));
        }
        MainActivity.mac.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Creating static Mainactivity field in Mainactivity.cs.

```
  public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity mac;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        initFontScale();
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
       
        mac = this;
```

Now, using DependencyService to fire.

```
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IBattery>().getbattery();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. That works a treat. Thank you for sharing your wisdom ...! :)

Comment: that works perfectly fine but do you know if there is a way to restore the setting? I need in my app to on/off this setting.

Comment: Any idea to have "Android.Net" does not exist build error, even I added "using Android.Net" on top?

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` add two properties:

```
private const int RequestPermissionsId = 0
```

and

```
private readonly string[] ManifestPermissions =
{
    Manifest.Permission.RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations
    // Add here other permissions you want to check
}
```

Then override the OnStart method and force permission check there:

```
public override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();
    
    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
    {
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations != Permission.Granted)
            RequestPermissions(ManifestPermissions, RequestPermissionsId);
    }
}
```

And of course, remember that you must have the `OnRequestPermissionsResult` method implemented:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It lead me to a section of the docs I had overlooked.  I still have the issue that the app is still set for battery optimization by default. I've updated my question with the latest details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am guessing you are trying to check it directly through shared code

The easiest way to do it would be to extend the needed permission in native using essentials.

Check the status and request permission through an interface:

```
 public interface IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations
 {
    Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync();
    Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync();
 }
```

Implement the native part for the same:

```
 public class IgnoreBatteryOptimizationsPlatformPermission : Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.BasePlatformPermission, IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations
 {
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions =>
             new (string, bool)[] { (Manifest.Permission.RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations, true) };
 }
```

Then register it in your Native XF caller class(MainActivity, Appdelegate(for some other permission))

```
 DependencyService.Register<IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations, IgnoreBatteryOptimizationsPlatformPermission>();
```

And then in your XF class use this method:

```
 public static async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestBatteryOptimizations()
    {
        var batteryOptimizationsPermission = DependencyService.Get<IRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations>();
        var status = await batteryOptimizationsPermission.CheckStatusAsync();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            status = await batteryOptimizationsPermission.RequestAsync();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

And then request for it whenever you like:

```
var status= await CheckAndRequestBatteryOptimizations();
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#extending-permissions

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I gave it a try, but the result was the same, in that the app was still set to optimize battery. No errors/exceptions though. I then took a different approach following the Xamarin Essentials docs on extending permissions, but again, same incorrect result. Please see UPDATE in my question.